# WPF: Command design any ideas?

Tags: c#, wpf

We have several commands that more or less do the same kind of functionality dispersed across different namespaces and projects in our wpf solution.

We need to add some base functionality to ALL these commands across the projects so that their canExecute checks for a condition and based on that hides any ui elements if it returns false.

This "check" is common for ALL these commands, which is basically checking for right to do something.
Is  there a way in wpf I can maybe use some common piece of code to do that...instead of finding all these commands and updating the canExecute method? Maybe attached behaviors? I am not sure what would be the best thing. I tried creating a common base command and have the other commands extend that, but that involves a lot of refactoring.
Thank you

Comment: The common base class is probably all you can do, but shouldn't be THAT complicated.

Comment: Aspect Oriented Programming? ;-) But seriously, cases like this one is a huge sign for required refactoring. Go over the code and regroup all the commands now so it'll take less effort the next time you discover such a need.

Comment: Either have a shared base class or use Aspect Oriented Programming: http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/security